# PHP - How to group file owner from an array?

Tags: php

I have this array:

```
$files = [
    'text.php'     => 'Philip Adams',
    'help.php'     => 'Bobby Barnett',
    'video.php'    => 'Philip Adams',
    'events.php'   => 'Bruce Aguilar',
    'mysql.php'    => 'Bobby Barnett',
    'sunday.php'   => 'Victoria Rose',
    'facebook.php' => 'Bobby Barnett',
    'blog.php'     => 'Philip Adams',
    'view.php'     => 'Victoria Rose',
];
```

Now, I want to make the array like this:

```
$files = [
    'Philip Adams'     => [
        'text.php',
        'video.php',
        'blog.php',
    ],
    'Bobby Barnett'     => [
        'help.php',
        'mysql.php',
        'facebook.php',
    ],
    'Bruce Aguilar'    => [
        'events.php',
    ],
    'Victoria Rose'   => [
        'sunday.php',
        'view.php',
    ],

];
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Have you tried anything?  `foreach()` over your initial array?

Comment: I have checked with `array_flip($files)` but can't make like the output i need

Comment: `array_flip` is wrong here to begin with, because you can not use the same key more than once, you you will lose part of your input data, when you do that.

Comment: then can you tell me what is the right away?

Comment: All you have to do is loop over what you got, and use the value of your input array, as key for your output array. And then you append the original keys (which become your values in the new array), to the entry with that key.

Comment: Ah! can't understand

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can loop the existing array by key/value and push to a new array, something like:

```
$output = []; // Declare an empty array to hold the output 

// Loop the $files array by $file (eg: text.php) and $owner (eg: Philip Adams)
foreach($files as $file => $owner){
  $output[$owner][] = $file; // Add the $file to the $owner key in the new array
}

print_r($output); // Output the array
```

[Working example](https://3v4l.org/sEUQo)

Comment: Thousand Thanks to You!

Comment: This is not what the OP wants. The flies have to be divided by comma within one and the same string.

Comment: @mitkosoft where do you see that? According to the expected output in the question, OP wants an array of values: `['text.php','video.php','blog.php'],`

Comment: @BrettGregson, that’s correct, but regarding the desired output, all the files should be comma separated with additional single quotas as a single string, but but not in separate array values, i.e. you have to implode() them,

Comment: @mitkosoft where do you see this in the question?

Comment: @BrettGregson, to be precise - I don't see array index for each file into the desired output, but just need of a string, like `[Philip Adams] => ['text.php','video.php','blog.php']` which is slightly different from `[Philip Adams] => Array
        (
            [0] => text.php
            [1] => video.php
            [2] => blog.php
        )`, no?

Comment: @BrettGregson, my mistake, apologies. +1 from me.

Comment: @mitkosoft No worries, it is Monday :D